# error `bash: prompt_git` report when no git operations performed

Tags: bash, git

I occasionally encounter such an error:

```
$ which bash
/usr/local/bin/bash
bash: prompt_git: command not found
```

The report is obscure, since I did not manipulate git. When it's rebooted, the error disappear. However, it will abruptly emerge after some uncertain operations were executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are having is caused by a bad setting in your `.bash_profile`/`.bashrc` file.

One of the shell variables `PS1` or `PROMPT_COMMAND` contains a call to `prompt_git` which is not (at that point) in your `PATH`. `PS1` defines the prompt you see in the terminal and `PROMPT_COMMAND` is run every time the prompt is displayed.

Comment: ty, I am reading introductions about `PS1`